# Implementing adaptive thresholding filter with SVG filters

Tags: svg, svg-filters

Is that possible to create the adaptive threshold filter with svg?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to simulate a local adaptive threshold using a series of feConvolveMatrixes combined with a series of feBlends. I have written a median filter this way before. But it's complicated and the performance is poor. (It is far easier to just write this in Canvas - which is better at pixel processing.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please give me your try?